# Run macro automatically via vbscript from timer

Tags: vba, vbscript, task, scheduler

I have a macro that downloads some information from the internet and I need to schedule it to run automatically starting at a certain time of day and running repeatedly both at set time intervals although occasionally at specific times output by the macro.

I have approached the problem in two ways, both of which have presented problems that I can't figure out. The first approach is using a timer sub that runs the macro using the Application.OnTime command with the runtime derived from a cell in the workbook that is updated by the macro.

This method works pretty well if I am on the computer doing something else. However, I have noticed that if I leave, even if the computer doesn't go to sleep, the program inevitably stops re-running after 30min or so. Sometimes it also stops re-running even when I'm active on the computer. Why is this? What could be causing this? Also, naturally, I can't schedule the program to open and run automatically from within the macro, so I turned to the VBScript & Task Scheduler method for this part of the solution.

I have, however, encountered two problems with the execution of the VBScript. First, is that it often fails to start when run by Task Scheduler. Second, is that when it does run, the Application.OnTime command within the macro doesn't work. This is a problem because the macro needs to run sometimes at irregular time intervals which are determined during the course of the day as the macro runs through its iterations. Why would the vbscript fail to run when task manager tries, and why would it not initiate the application.ontime command the way the macro does when I run it manually?

VBA Timer Code:

```
Sub Timer()
    Dim Runtime As Date

    If Time <= TimeValue("17:45:00") Then
        Workbooks("10am_Swing_Report").Sheets("Parameters").Cells(17, 2).Value = 10
    ElseIf Time > TimeValue("17:45:00") And Time <= TimeValue("18:15:00") Then
        Workbooks("10am_Swing_Report").Sheets("Parameters").Cells(17, 2).Value = 13
    ElseIf Time > TimeValue("18:15:00") And Time <= TimeValue("18:45:00") Then
        Workbooks("10am_Swing_Report").Sheets("Parameters").Cells(17, 2).Value = 16
    ElseIf Time > TimeValue("18:45:00") And Time <= TimeValue("19:15:00") Then
        Workbooks("10am_Swing_Report").Sheets("Parameters").Cells(17, 2).Value = 19
    End If

    Workbooks("10am_Swing_Report").Sheets("Parameters").Range("B16").Calculate
    If Time > Workbooks("10am_Swing_Report").Sheets("Parameters").Range("B16").Value Then
        Runtime = Time + TimeValue("00:00:30")
    Else
        Runtime = Workbooks("10am_Swing_Report").Sheets("Parameters").Range("B16").Value
    End If

    Application.OnTime TimeValue(Runtime), "Swingtimer"

    Workbooks("10am_Swing_Report").Sheets("Parameters").Range("C16").Value = Runtime
    Workbooks("10am_Swing_Report").Save
End Sub
```

Thanks!

I've updated the Vbs code to include a validation that the runtime has been passed, but I'm still encountering a problem with Task Scheduler failing to start the task. I'm getting the following error: "Launch request ignored, instance already running" followed by: "Task Start Failed". I was originally thinking this was because the Vbscript was still running from the previous instance, but I'm getting this from the very beginning.

```
Option Explicit


Dim xlApp       
Dim xlBook      
Dim runtime 
Dim xlSheet



Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
'xlApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\DORIAN\Dropbox\Swing_Report.xlsm",1,False)
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets("Parameters")

'xlBook.application.Visible = True

'MsgBox FormatDateTime(xlSheet.Range("B16").Value,3)
runtime = TimeValue(FormatDateTime(xlSheet.Range("B16").Value,3))
'MsgBox runtime


If Time > runtime Then 
    xlApp.Run "Swingtimer"
    'MsgBox "Running..."
    WScript.Sleep 30000
Else
xlApp.Application.OnTime runtime, "Swingtimer"
'MsgBox "Timer Set"
End If


xlbook.close True

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Please provide the code of both the VBA and VBScript parts. Like it is stated now, there is not much that can be provided as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do it in a different way?
1)
Run vbscript it in Windows Scheduler say every 1 minute or 1 hour or ….

2)
Put some validation inside VBscript
If Condition then 
    Execute your code
Else
    Stop vbscript
End if

Using this you probably can get rid of OnTime event handler

Best regards
Alex

Comment: Thanks. I currently have it set up on task scheduler to run every five minutes. I dont want it to run more frequently, but sometimes it needs to run in between tje five minute intervals, i.e. at 8:52 when it would normally run at 8:50 & 8:55. I was wondering if i could draw the run time from the workbook into the vbscript instead of into vba. But i cant figure out how to make it work. 

Regarding a validation of some kind, i dont have anything to validate. I want the program to run every five minutes, but sometimes in between as well.

Comment: @Dorian821, you can modify the task scheduler to be triggered by an event and timer (search on stackoverflow on how to create event using vbs).

Comment: @Dorian821 When I used the term 'validation' I meant the decision: to run or not to run based on your conditions. For example your scheduler 'fires' every 1 minute: 8:50 - run (by time); 8:51 - not run; 8:52 - run (by some extra condition); 8:53 - not run, etc

Comment: @alex Ahh, ok. Could I use a value within the workbook as the condition? or would I have to create an event log as suggested above to test for?

Comment: I think the Excel value is simpler. You already have some vbscript, so it's better to avoid 2 source of codes. Something like this

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Alex\Tasks\VBScript_and_Excel\ex.xlsx")

dim s
s = objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value

objExcel.Quit

if s = "run" then
 ...  do something ...
else
 wscript.Quit
end if

Comment: Make sure your password is entered correctly.  It is the password to sign onto your machine.  The password must be entered correctly for the Scheduler to run it.  You are giving it the rights to run a task, as you, when you are not on the machine.  I believe the Scheduler lets you enter the incorrect password and doesn't prompt you for this.  Maybe there is a reason for this, but it seems like it's more of a lack of oversight by Windows developers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over complicating things.  You just need a Workbook_Open event and Windows Task Scheduler.

Something like this (customize to suit your needs).

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Msgbox Date
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Date
End Sub
```

Schedule the event using the Windows Task Scheduler.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html

Comment: thanks. You're right that I could make it simpler. Currently, however, the code works fine, and I prefer the validation to prevent the vba code from running unnecessarily. The problem seems to actually be found with task scheduler. The script runs great manually, but I'm encountering continual problems getting it to run on a schedule with task scheduler. At the moment, it doesn't seem to even open the script. It stalls at "Created Task Process", and just remains there for hours. Meanwhile there is no trace of a wscript or the Excel process in Task Manager

Comment: This is a better solution. If you want an ad-hoc run, modify the task to run on an event log.  You can write a vbs module to create the event and put it on desktop short cut.

Comment: I don't see how that would help or simplify things. The criteria for the program are simply time based and I want it to be running automatically on my server on a daily basis. Consequently, how can setting up another program with a desktop shortcut and event logs work better than a time based schedule?

Comment: Actually, the vbs & vba parts of the program work fine now, the issue at this point is that Task Scheduler doesn't actually open the vbs file even though it says that it is. Consequently, I can't get it automated.